# Reminder for user to save

Tags: web-app, save

In the admin of the web app I work on, we never auto-save user input. They are required to press a "Save" button. In certain places I worry the user might forget to save and lose their input. I was considering adding a subtle animation to the save button to remind them to press it. How have different applications handled this issue?

Comment: What I've seen is applications prompting the user if they try to navigate away from the page and there are unsaved changes. Personally I find animations like you want to do very distracting, in a bad way.

Comment: If the application takes the effort to remind the user to save, why not simply save? It seems weird.

Comment: What user action do you propose would activate the button animation?

Comment: When the user has copied two things that they need to paste into an external third-party application @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: @Andy because we are not using autosave anywhere else in the admin so that seems weird to only do it here. We are particularly worried about the user not saving on this page because we know that they will need to navigate to a different website to paste some tokens

Comment: "When the user has copied..." Do you provide a "copied thing" confirmation of some sort?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yes a little message pops up next to it saying "Copied"

Comment: What do you think of adding a "Save now?" button/link along with that "Copied" notice? So the user can click that and their input is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Having the save button wiggle, flash, rotate, pump, whatever isn't ideal, especially when it's on a timer and might distract the user from the thing they're filling out.

A better solution would be the standard onbeforeunload prompt - "you have unsaved changes, do you really want to leave the site?" This is the solution the vast majority of the web uses.

And a better solution still would be to autosave the content locally, rather than sending it to the server. This is the solution discord uses so you can navigate between channels and keep your input.